# Combine multiple SELECT queries into a single VIEW

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view

## Combine These Queries

I want a view which combines multiple queries. Something like

```
SELECT
  products.id AS id
FROM products
```

```
SELECT
  publications.visible AS online_visible
FROM products
INNER JOIN publications ON publications.product_id = products.id
WHERE publication.name = 'online'
```

```
SELECT
  publications.visible AS retail_visible
FROM products
INNER JOIN publications ON publications.product_id = products.id
WHERE publication.name = 'retail'
```

```
SELECT
  SUM(sales.quantity) AS year_sales
FROM products
LEFT OUTER JOIN sales ON sales.product_id = products.id
WHERE sales.date > current_date - interval '365' day
GROUP BY products.id
```

```
SELECT
  SUM(sales.quantity) AS month_sales
FROM products
LEFT OUTER JOIN sales ON sales.product_id = products.id
WHERE sales.date > current_date - interval '30' day
GROUP BY products.id
```

## Desired End Result

What I want in the end is a table like

```
| ID |online_visible|retail_visible|month_sales|year_sales|
|----|--------------|--------------|-----------|----------|
|  1 |   false      |    true      |     35    |   420    |
```

## Givens

- I have tested each of the queries individually on their own, so I know they each work.
- You can probably assume that any typo here is caused by me trying to simplify my question and isn't the cause of my problem.
- It's likely my question has been asked before but I don't know enough SQL to ask the right question

## What I have tried

I have tried a number of combinations where I use UNION or UNION ALL to combine the queries.

Combine with that I made each SELECT includes all of the other SELECTs but with null values.
Like, this

```
SELECT
  products.id AS id,
  null::boolean AS online_visible,
  null::boolean AS retail_visible,
  null:int AS month_sales,
  null:int AS year_sales
FROM products
```

and similar for the others

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I do have "Desired End Result" section. Is there more that you would like? I could add sample data which I don't have.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired result with this query:

```sql
WITH products_publications AS (
  SELECT
    products.id AS id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN publication.name = 'online' THEN publications.visible END) 
      AS online_visible,
    MAX(CASE WHEN publication.name = 'retail' THEN publications.visible END) 
      AS retail_visible
  FROM products
  INNER JOIN publications ON publications.product_id = products.id
  WHERE publication.name IN ('online', 'retail')
  GROUP BY products.id
), products_sales AS (
  SELECT
    products.id AS id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sales.date > current_date - interval '30' day 
        THEN sales.quantity END) AS month_sales,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sales.date > current_date - interval '365' day 
        THEN sales.quantity END) AS year_sales
  FROM products
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sales ON sales.product_id = products.id
  GROUP BY products.id
)
SELECT
  p.id,
  pp.online_visible,
  pp.retail_visible,
  ps.month_sales,
  ps.year_sales
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN products_publications pp ON pp.id = p.id
LEFT JOIN products_sales ps ON ps.id = p.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` clause to get it efficiently like below:

```
select 
    pr.id "id",
    coalesce(bool_or(pu.visible) filter (where pu.name='online'),false) "online_visible",
    coalesce(bool_or(pu.visible) filter (where pu.name='retail'),false) "retail_visible",
    coalesce(sum(sa.quantity) filter  (where sa.date > current_date - interval '365' day),0) "year_sales",
    coalesce(sum(sa.quantity) filter  (where sa.date > current_date - interval '30' day),0) "month_sales"
from products pr
left join publications pu on pr.id=pu.product_id
left join sales sa on sa.product_id=pr.id
group by 1
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=084d9bed2787068dd015ba0d428c4952)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.  I think I might approach this by aggregating along the separate dimensions and then `JOIN`ing:

```
SELECT p.id, (pu.num_online > 0) as online_visible,
      (pu.num_retail > 0) as retail_visible,
       s.monthly_sales, s.yearly_sales
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT pu.product_id,
             COUNT(*) OVER (FILTER BY pu.name = 'online') as num_online,
             COUNT(*) OVER (FILTER BY pu.name = 'retail') as num_retail             
      FROM publications pu
      GROUP BY pu.product_id
     ) pu
     ON pu.product_id = p.id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT s.products_id, SUM(s.quantity) AS year_sales,
             SUM(s.quantity) FILTER (WHERE s.date > current_date - interval '30' day) as month_sales
      FROM sales s
      WHERE s.date > current_date - interval '365' day
      GROUP BY s.id
     ) s
     ON s.product_id = p.id;
```

This ensures that the `JOIN`s do not inadvertently multiply rows, throwing off aggregation values -- particularly for sales.

Note that you don't need the `products` table in the subqueries.